# How to track unique visitors and page views in rails without javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to track unique visitors and their page views in rails without javascript?
In general I only need to count them.

Comment: why do you not want to use javascript ?

Comment: @tgkprog, I dont know it.

Comment: @Dmitry since you don't have a technical reason, you should really look into using Google Analytics and/or Gauges.

Answer (score 7):

Setup an PageViews-Model and create the tracking stuff like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_filter  :pageview

  def pageview
    PageView.create :user_id              => ...
                    :referer              => request.referrer,
                    :session              => request.session_options[:id],
                    :ip_address           => request.remote_ip,
                    :user_agent           => request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
                    :created_at           => Time.current
  end
end
```

The uniqueness can be reached when you compare new ip's with already saved ones.

Comment: request.referrer can easily be a very long string, so be sure to have column type :text, or trim the referrer down to its domain

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.remote_ip` to track user IPs and then apply your rules.

Comment: What do you mean "apply your rules"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not want to use cookies but want to track unique visitors in the back end?

Use remote_ip to track IP and use script to get adobe global id and store it in DB.

Cases can be : more than 1 PC using IP (shared internet like in an office) so will get same IP but different adobe ids.

Different IP and different Adobe

Same or different IP and no adobe id (default to 0)

In all cases can keep the unique string as a combination of the two

Comment: I dont mind to use cookies, I was hoping that there is some complex (and ready-to-use) solution...

Comment: i guess you can keep this open for a few days and see what else is suggested. did you use google to search for solutions?